# grails 2.5 does not read properties from home dir when added to grails.config.locations

Tags: grails

At the top of config.groovy is this line (now uncommented):

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties"]
```

So we created a properties file on windows in our home dir /.grails, which contains these lines for the database migration plugin:

```
contents of c:\Users\me\.grails\myapp-config.properties:

grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartContexts=XXX
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart=true
```

we restart the app, it completely ignores these values.

If however, we change to a groovy file thusly:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

And create the following file: c:\Users\me.grails\myapp-config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartContexts = 'XXX'
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
```

It works perfectly.  It seems it is not possible to use property files with the database migration plugin at least.

However, we need to be able to change these values on production (tomcat + war), which we assume cannot compile groovy files, so wont work.

Luckily, the below part does actually work:

```
 if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
     grails.config.locations << "file:" +       System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
 }
```

But we would really like to get the home dir version working, so we dont have to worry about system properties and command line arguments in our dev environments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you assume that groovy files won't work in production? That's not correct. We use groovy files in production for external configurations all the time.

Comment: So if you are running a war file in tomcat, which is using a JRE in production (not jdk), it can still compile groovy?  We did not think that the war would include a groovy compiler!  Perhaps we are confused because the goovy files are not actually goovy, but a subset used by the configSlurper thing?

Comment: That is correct. They are used by the Config Slurper and work just fine using the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the path separator for windows from / to \
2. try to put the complete path in locations to check the file can be read